# as3 delete row in datagrid to filter data

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Im trying to filter a datagrid by deleting row if value of column is not equal to my input... But the if condition does not seem to work... Below is my code:

```
for(var k:int =0; k<DataGrid.length;k++){
    wew = DataGrid.getItemAt(k).Name.toString();
    if(txt_username.text != wew){
        trace("not equal");
        DataGrid.removeItemAt(k); // remove row if it does not equal to   name input by user
    }
    else{
        trace("same");
    }
    }
}
```

Sample data :

```
John    val1    val2   val3
Awts    val1    val2   val3
Awts    val1    val2   val3
```

User input: "John"

Desired output:

```
John    val1   val2   val3
```

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some little problems in your code :

- `DataGrid` is a class name which you can use to create an instance that you can use in your code, like this for example :

  ```
  var data_grid:DataGrid = new DataGrid();
  addChild(data_grid);
  ```

  then you can use that instance :

  ```
  for(var k:int = 0; k < data_grid.length; k++){
      // ...
  }
  ```
- Your `wow` var should be a declared string :

  ```
  var wow:String = data_grid.getItemAt(k).Name.toString();
  ```

so your code can be like this :

```
for(var k:int = 0; k < data_grid.length; k++){
    var wew:String = data_grid.getItemAt(k).Name.toString();
    if(txt_username.text != wew){
        data_grid.removeItemAt(k);
        k --;
    }
}
```

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 0):

you dont even have to delete the data's using this , if you need to filter the datas and not delete the values you can use the filter function for the array collection and you can able to do it , try googling.